# I'm building a REST client to access a service that requires an Authorization header but I don't know how ti implement that

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, webservice-client

I've been doing lot's of SOAP but I'm a newby when it comes to REST.  I'm building a client to access a service that requires me to include an authorization token.  It needs to be in a header but I've skimmed through a PACKT book I purchased online and the 2.17 User's Guide off the web site.  And what I can't figure out is how to add that Authorization header.  Could anyone help me out or point me a document that has example in it.

Thanks,
Rob Tanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

Simply call [`header`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html#header%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) on the [`Invocation.Builder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html)

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Response response = target.request().header("Authorization", "AuthValue").get();
```

---

Check out sections [5.3.3 - 5.3.5 in the User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4405).

What may be a little confusing is that most of the examples you will see, makes use of method chaining, so you don't see all the actual types returned by those method calls, which make it hard to look for the proper documentation.

Basically, when you call [`request()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html#request%28%29) on the [`WebTarget`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html), you get back an [`Invocation.Builder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html)

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();
```

If you look at the `Invocation.Builder` Javadoc I linked to, you will find a bunch of method you can chain to build the request. One of the methods is [`header(name, value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html#header%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29). That's where you can set the header

```
builder = builder.header("Authorization": "Some value");
```

Once you're done building, you can build the request by calling one of the [`buildXxx()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html#buildGet%28%29), which returns in [`Invocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.html), from which you can [`invoke()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.html#invoke%28%29) the request.

```
Response response = builder.buildGet().invoke();
```

If you look at the `Invocation.Builder` API, you will see that it extends [`SyncInvoker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html), which has shorthand methods. So, for instance, instead of calling `builder.builderGet().invoke()`, we are allowed to simply call `builder.get()`.

So putting that all together we would have something like

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

Invocation.Builder builder = target.request();
builder = builder.header("Authorization", "Some Value");
Response response = builder.get();
```

Or to make things simple and chain everything

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Response response = target.request().header(..., ...).get();
```